# PHP - Remove substring which begins and ends with particular characters from parent string

Tags: php

I have two files, index.md and subPage.md. This is file index.md:

```
---
Title: Index page
Description: This is a sample description.
Keywords: Those, are, keywords.
Template: index
---
# Hello!
This is an Index.md file.
```

and this is sub.md:

```
---
Title: Sub Page
---
# Again hello
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

On file index.php I'm getting content of those files:

```
$indexPage = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/index.md');
$subPage = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/subPage.md');
```

I need to remove the snippet which begins and ends with *---* on each file. The problem is that the PHP file has to detect the substring which begins and ends with those three characters on both files. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just to be clear, what is the expected strings supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp for this, try this one: https://regexr.com/49l2p

Here is quick code example:

```
<?php

$indexPage = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/index.md');
$subPage = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/subPage.md');

$pattern = '/^---\n[\w\W]+---\n/m';

$indexReplaced = preg_replace($pattern, '', $indexPage);
$subPageReplaced = preg_replace($pattern, '', $subPage);

var_dump($indexReplaced, $subPageReplaced);
```

The pattern is first looking for `---` at the beginning of the string, then it looks for everything which is after that, finally it looks for second `---` and a new line after that. Very simple regexp :)

Comment: ```$pattern = preg_replace($pattern, '', $indexPage);
$indexReplaced = preg_replace($pattern, '', $indexPage);
```
For not get first return carriage `\n`

Comment: @abkrim sorry, I do not understand

Comment: Code no clean a return carriage after last --- . With this `$pattern = '/^---[^-]+---\n/m';
` , result start at "#Hello..."

Comment: @abkrim I have changed the RegExp slightly